# Calling python script from subprocess not outputting

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have code in two environments, a windows machine with a Linux VM. I'm trying to create a script that builds the code on the windows side via a script, `buildWindows.py` , run on the Linux side.

I'm having the script ssh over to the windows side, and then run a python builder script `windowsBuilder.py`.

The issue I'm having is that the python builder script on the windows side takes a while to run, and nothing is being printed out until the program finishes. Is there a way to have the output print while the script is running, versus when it ends?

I'm assuming I'm having this issue because when you call a python script, it opens a new python environment, and it only returns information once the python environment is finished.

subprocess call in `buildWindows.py`:

```
COMMAND = "cd C:/codeLocation/; python windowsBuilder.py"
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % IP_ADDRESS, COMMAND],
                   shell=False,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(ssh.stdout.readline, ''):
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn off buffering: `bufsize=0` parameter passed to call

```
 ssh = subprocess.call(["ssh", "%s" % IP_ADDRESS, COMMAND],
                   shell=False,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   bufsize=0)
```

Comment: I tried adding `bufsize=0` to my subprocess call and it didn't seem to change anything. I accidentally said that I was using `subprocess.call` when I'm actually using `subprocess.Popen` sorry for the mix up.

Comment: maybe windowsBuilder.py is also buffering its output...
you could try to add "sys.stdout.flush() after printing each line

Comment: I tried adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after the line is printed, but it didn't seem to change anything. The first thing that happens in the `windowsBuilder.py` script, is that it prints the name of the script, the time, and the arguments that were passed. I'm only seeing that output after the script has fully finished.